# PyQt / PySide keyPressEvent default behaviour

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I've subclassed QPlainTextEdit and want to catch certain keys.  If the key pressed isn't one of these, proceed with default behaviour (adding text, for example).

Is this possible, or do I have to program that too?

Example:

```
def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() in [16777235, 16777237, 16777234, 16777236, 16777220]: # Up, down, left, right, return.
            event.ignore()
        else:
            event.doDefault()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done using super:

```
def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() in [16777235, 16777237, 16777234, 16777236, 16777220]: # Up, down, left, right, return.
            event.ignore()
        else:
            super(MyTextEdit, self).keyPressEvent(event)
```